# «Для звука [j] нет буквы»

Tags: фонетика, алфавит, графика

«Для звука [j] в русском алфавите отсутствует отдельная буква, и он передается йотированной буквой» — говорится в учебнике русского языка для 10–11 классов, написанном Н. Г. Гольцовой и др.

Мне непонятен смысл утверждения, если учитывать, что в русском алфавите есть буква *й*, которая как раз и обозначает звук [j].

Быть может, я в чем-то ошибаюсь? Действительно ли для звука [j] отсутствует отдельная буква?

Answer (score 4):

Й — буква, которой в русском письме обозначались в разных случаях два совершенно разнородных звука.

Из Большой Советской Энциклопедии:

В системе русского письма Й обозначает неслоговой гласный (отнюдь не согласный среднеязычный фрикативный «j», с которым его часто неточно сопоставляют).

Трёхтомная «Грамматика русского языка»:"В ряде случаев буквы Е, Ё, Ю, Я обозначают сочетания согласного «й» с последующими гласными", а выше этого несколькими строками столкнуться с распределением русских фонем на 6 гласных и 41 согласную, причем в ряду этих последних обнаружится и «й».

В одних случаях, когда мы встречаем букву Й в словах «мой», «твой», «май», «чай», она выражает краткий неслоговой гласный «й»(иногда его называют полугласный), в других же — ну, скажем, в имени английского графства Йорк или арабского государства Йемен — передает бесспорный согласный «йот».

Таких слов немного. В БСЭ их всего 59. Шесть из числа географических названий СССР (нерусских), 53 — относятся к зарубежным топонимам или понятиям, заимствованным из чужих языков.

Из всех  перечисленных русских букв Й в некотором роде «Иван, родства не помнящий». В кириллице никакой буквы Й не было. Её ввели в употребление только в 1735 году. При этом до самой революции буква Й была каким-то полупризнанным знаком. Ни в «Толковом словаре» В. Даля, ни в «Энциклопедическом словаре» Брокгауза и Эфрона, естественно, нет такого раздела: «Слова на букву Й». У Брокгауза за названием сибирской речки «Iя» сразу же следует буква «К».
http://uchitel-slovesnosti.ru/publ/uvlekatelnoe_jazykoznanie/interesno_o_bukvakh/bukva_j/89-1-0-1685

Лопатин закрепил написание Й после гласных в конце слова или перед согласными (май, елей, кий, рой,тайна, лейка),но звуки, ей обозначаемые, не разграничил. Может, чтобы не путать обычных граждан, нефилологов.

Перед гласной буква й пишется только в следующих случаях:

Если буквой й кончается первая часть сложносокращенного слова, а вторая начинается с гласной, напр.: райадминистрация, крайизбирком, стройиндустрия, стройотряд, райуполномоченный.

А дальше пишет уже о йоте:

В ограниченном круге слов иноязычного происхождения, в том числе в собственных именах, й пишется перед о в начале слова или после гласных: йог, йога, йогурт, йод, йомен, йоркширы (порода свиней), йот, йота, йотация; койот, майолика, майонез, майор, майорат, район; в собственных именах:Йорк, Йоркшир, Йошкар-Ола, Йорик, Иоганнес, Йорген, Йокосука; Айова, Вайоминг, Вийон, Лойола, Огайо и др.

В некоторых словах иноязычного происхождения буква й пишется перед буквами е, ю, я, и, напр.: вилайет, дуайен, фойе, стайер, конвейер, фейерверк, кикуйю (народность), аллилуйя, вайя, майя, маракуйя, папайя, паранойя, тупайя; секвойя, секвойи, секвойе, секвойю; в собственных именах: Йемен, Йена, Йенсен, Йейтс, Йеллоустонский, Мейерхольд, Рамбуйе, Хейер-дал, Йёринг, Байер, Йиглава, Майя, Байярд, Вайян; Гойя, Гойи, Гойе, Гойю.

А вообще-то йот прячется в Е,Ё,Ю,Я.

История буквы хорошо описана в Википедии, почитайте.

Буква Й обозначает палатальный аппроксимант [j] (так называемое и неслоговое) и близкий к нему звонкий палатальный фрикативный согласный [ʝ] (перед ударным гласным). В украинском и болгарском языках сочетание йо используется в начале слов и после гласных вместо отсутствующей в них буквы Ё.

Знак Й происходит из церковнославянской письменности XV—XVI веков, представляя собой сочетание буквы И и заимствованного из греческой письменности знака краткости — бреве, однако несколько видоизменённого.

Строгое фонетическое разграничение начертаний И и Й возникло в печати начала XVII века; в ходе «книжной справы» времен патриарха Никона оно перешло в московские издания церковнославянских книг (вторая половина того же века) и используется поныне.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за ответ (зная, что вы учитель, я рассчитывал на него), но ведь в той же Википедии черным по белому написано: «Буква Й обозначает палатальный аппроксимант [j] (так называемое и неслоговое) **и** близкий к нему звонкий палатальный фрикативный согласный [ʝ] (перед ударным гласным)». То есть как раз для нашего йота (который звонкий палатальный спирант) есть буква в русском алфавите — Й... Вы не думаете, что в учебнике Гольцовой дана слишком спорная формулировка? (Я, конечно, примерно понимаю, что авторы имели в виду: разграничить и неслоговое и, собственно, йот.)

Comment: Я сама всё время спотыкаюсь на этом. Видимо, Гольцова хочет сказать о том, что йота как такового в русском языке нет, в других есть, а в русском нет, у нас это полугласный поющийся звук, а когда появились соответствующие заимствования, появился и йот, мы ж стараемся правильно произнести иноязычные слова, вот и приспособили свою букву для обозначения этого звука.

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю конкретно. Формулировка, конечно, у Гольцовой "отставляет желать".
Но, если поднапрячься, понять можно.

В русском алфавите есть буква Й, но она не является **отдельной буквой**, закрепленной за звуком Йот. Основная нагрузка Й - передача полугласного (неслогового) И. Или (при другом подходе к фонетике) - второго элемента нисходящих дифтонгов АЙ, ОЙ, УЙ, ЭЙ. *ИЙ - тоже, но я выношу его за скобки, он специфичен как дифтонг.*
Это не дает права называть без существенных оговорок букву Й буквой для передачи звука "Йот".

С другой стороны, основная нагрузка по передаче собственно звука "Йот" ложится на "йотирующие гласные буквы" - Е, Ё, Ю, Я.

Для сравнения. В украинском есть еще буква Ї, передающая сочетание звуков ЙИ. В русском в подобных случаях обходятся обычной буквой И, хотя фонетически это то же самое сочетание - по**и**ть, соловь**и**. 
С учетом близости языков это только подчеркивает отсутствие регулярного соответствия между буквой Й и звуком Й, который, напротив, регулярно передаётся другими буквами.

Вот об этом пишет Гольцова. Да, как сказал, формулировка у неё тяжелая и плохо воспринимается. Но все остальные объяснения - совсем не по делу. Или же не являются объяснениями вовсе, а только занимательными историями.

> Лопатин закрепил написание Й после гласных в конце слова или перед
>   согласными (май, елей, кий, рой,тайна, лейка),

Лопатин??? Без малого 300 лет ждал?

> Из всех перечисленных русских букв Й в некотором роде «Иван, родства
>   не помнящий». В кириллице никакой буквы Й не было. Её ввели в
>   употребление только в 1735 году. При этом до самой революции буква Й
>   была каким-то полупризнанным знаком. Ни в «Толковом словаре» В. Даля,
>   ни в «Энциклопедическом словаре» Брокгауза и Эфрона, естественно, нет
>   такого раздела: «Слова на букву Й». У Брокгауза за названием сибирской
>   речки «Iя» сразу же следует буква «К».

Околесина какая-то. Буква вполне себе существовала, но слова, с неё начинающиеся в современной орфографии, тогда регулярно писались через I (i с точкой). Й прочно заняла её место только с  реформой орфографии - да и то не сразу.