# Правильно ли писать "безйодовая диета", но "безйотово произносимое слово"?

Tags: орфография

Правильно писать *безйодовая диета* и *безйотово произносимое слово*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 —  У вас нет йогурта? Тогда можно испечь 
  безйогуртовый торт с таким же вкусом.

 —  Так писать нельзя! Слова безйогуртовый нет в 
  словаре.
 
  — А почему безйодовый и безйотовый есть?
```

**ОТВЕТ**

Эти слова (***безйодовый*** и ***безйотовый***) есть в орографическом словаре РАН, но такое написание не соответствует **правилам**.

1. **Конфликт между правилами и словарем РАН?**

Такое случается.  Изменяется практика письма, ставятся новые задачи, приходит другое понимание. Похожая ситуация с выбором Н и НН в кратких прилагательных, например  **[в недавней теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476820/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B).**

В этом случае прав всегда **электронный ресурс РАН**, который обновляется постоянно. С ним и надо сверяться в первую очередь.

2. **Ситуация с буквой Й интересная.** Буква одна, а звука два: полугласный скользящий [j] и палатальный гласный Й?  Вернее **два варианта** произношения одной фонемы
   Вот обсуждение ситуации **[на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435137/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-j-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B).** Вот **[еще материал](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3463381-pochemu-bukvu-j-nekogda-nazyvali-poluglasnoj.html).**
3. Но об этом в правилах **не говорится.** Там речь идет о букве Й, причем в **ограниченном** круге слов (начало слова или после гласного):

***стройотряд*** — сложносокращенных словах; ***йог**, йога, йогурт, йод* — в **начале** слова; ***фойе,** конвейер, фейерверк* — перед буквами **е, ю, я, и**; ***Йемен**, Йена, Йенсен* — **в собственных именах.**

**Какой звук** мы здесь обозначаем? При фонетическом разборе **нет указаний.**   [ф’ий’ирв’эрк], сравнить:  [пай’эхал].

4. **А  после согласного можно писать букву Й?**

Нет, там нужен **разделительный** знак Ъ или Ь.

**Но почему?** Обычно разделительный знак пишется для того, чтобы **согласный**  не произносился слитно с последующим **гласным** (между согласным и гласным находится звук Й: ***въехал, семья**.* Фонетический разбор: [вй’эхал]

5. Но в слове ***безйотовый*** звук Й уже обозначен, так какие тогда проблемы?  Ведь есть слова ***йот*** (звук) и ***йота*** (буква).

С точки зрения графики и фонетики они не просматриваются. А тогда зачем написали в правилах: "После согласных **буква й не пишется**"?

Никогда не говори ***никогда***? Или зачем?

Answer (score 6):

> Правильно писать *безйодовая диета* и *безйотово* произносимое слово?

**Правильно**. Оба этих слова — и  ***[безйодовый](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari)***, и ***[безйотовый](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari)** — есть в «**Русском орфографическом словаре***».

Правда, такое написание этих слов в настоящий момент противоречит правилу «*После согласных буква **й** не пишется*» (см. **[ПАС, § 26](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=22#pp22)**), но можно надеяться на то, что в будущем этот недочёт в правилах будет устранён.

Вот что пишет по поводу написания некоторых слов, приведенных  в РОС (в том числе и слова ***безйодовый***), один из редакторов «Русского орфографического словаря» Ольга Евгеньевна Иванова:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Вопросы культуры речи. Выпуск XI. 2019.)

Comment: А полный материал почитать можно?

Comment: _Безйотовый_ — это где нет буквы Й?

Comment: _Безйотовый_ — это где нет буквы Й?

Comment: йот — ЙОТ [ёт], а, м. В языкознании: согласный ЗВУК, изображаемый в латинском алфавите буквой j, в русском буквой «й» в конце слога (напр., бой, бойкот), а также открывающий собой слог, к-рый начинается буквами «е», «ё», «ю», «я» (напр., ель, боец, ёлка, маёвка, юг, союз, яма, сиять). Толковый словарь Ожегова

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/ushakov/%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%82

Comment: Йота  Буква греческого алфавита, обозначающая звук (и).   Также в других словарях:  https://znachenie-slova.ru/йота

Comment: @Серж  Орографическая концепция РОС.  ЭКСПЕРТНОЕ ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ на издание «Русский орфографический словарь» (Русский орфографический словарь. Доктор филологических наук, профессор, заместитель директора Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН М. Л. Каленчук  https://herzena.ru/public/files/dictionary/539b44817acbb__+3.Русский%20орфографический%20словарь_В.В.pdf

Comment: @Sharon спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (к первому ответу)**

Интересный материал по теме:

**Статья 1.**  **[Обозначение на письме фонемы [j]](https://info.wikireading.ru/276478)**

В современном русском языке существует **два варианта** произношения **звука [j].**  Вернее, **два варианта** произношения одной фонемы [j].

Первое (и основное) значение звука [j] проявляется в положении **перед гласным**: елка – [jo]лка, понимают – понима[jy]т.

Но **в конце слова или в конце слога** звук [j] **редуцируется,** становится кратким, приближаясь по звучанию к **гласному звуку [и].**  Нужно помнить, что [j] не совпадает с е [и]: ***каравай, стойте.***

(Добавлено к статье: фонетический разбор: **[стой’т’э], [каравай'].**)

На письме **буквой й** обозначают только **второй вариант произношения звука [j].** В некоторых заимствованных словах начальнослоговый [j] обозначается этой буквой й: ***йод, йог*** и т.д.

Не обозначается самостоятельной буквой фонема [j], когда она находится **перед гласным**. Так как в этом положении (в начале слова между гласными, перед гласным) на письме сочетание звука [j] и гласного **передается одной буквой я**-[ja]-ма; е[jэ]-ль; е-[jo]-лка; ю-[jy]-ла.

**Вопросы по статье**

И вот вопрос: **это надо изучать в школе?**  Может, **нужно понимание** с вариантами звука Й и письменным обозначением этих вариантов? Неужели это **трудно усвоить** обычным пользователям и нужно только филологам? Может быть, стоит обозначить решение хотя бы в упрощенном виде.

А как делать **фонетический разбор,** какой звук обозначать? Иногда такие вопросы возникают: обычная транскрипция слова: **[й’ама]. Или [ja]-ма?**

**[Статья 2](https://moluch.ru/archive/139/39143).**  **Принципы русской графики и способы передачи фонемы /j/**

Вне действия позиционного принципа графики находится **буква й:** она всегда передает одну и ту же **фонему /j/.**

В **ИСКОННО РУССКИХ** словах фонема /j/ обозначается тремя различными способами в зависимости от позиции, занимаемой этой фонемой.

**В начале слова** перед гласной и между гласными фонема /j/ вместе с последующими гласными фонемами /а/, /у/, /э/, /о/ обозначается буквами я, ю, е, ё. Например: яма, юг, ель, ёж, моя, мою, моей, моё.

**После согласной перед гласной** фонема /j/ вместе с последующей гласной обозначается буквами я, ю, е, ё, и, перед которыми пишется разделительный ь или ъ. Например: изъян, ладью, судье, подъезд, побьём, объём, чьи.

**После гласной перед согласной и на конце слова** /j/ обозначается буквой й. Например: стройка, чайник, мой.

Передача фонемы /j/ **в ИНОЯЗЫЧНЫХ словах** имеет ряд особенностей:

1. Буква й может использоваться для передачи фонемы /j/ и перед гласными в начале слова и после гласной. Например: ***йод, йогурт, район, майор, фойе, аллилуйя.***
2. После согласной сочетание фонем /jo/ может передаваться буквосочетанием **ьо**. Например: ***бульон, павильон, почтальон.***

После гласной **перед /и/** фонема /j/ на письме не обозначается. Поэтому одинаково передаются на письме сочетания фонем /аjи/, /иjи/, /оjи/, /уjи/, /эjи/ и /аи/, /ии/, /ои/, /уи/, /эи/.

Важно отметить, что, в отличие от исконно русских слов, в **ИНОЯЗЫЧНЫХ** словах эти способы применяются **непоследовательно** и для передачи одного и того же фонемного сочетания в одинаковой позиции в разных словах могут использоваться **разные способы.**

Говоря о графике, необходимо коснуться и некоторых предложений **по ее изменению, связанных со способами передачи фонемы .** После реформы 1917–1918 гг. В. П. Вахтеров предлагал проект нового **графического упрощения**: исключить буквы я, е, ё, ю с заменою их буквосочетаниями ***йа, йэ, йо, йу*** (после разделительных ъ и ь, в начале слова и после гласной) или буквосочетание ьа, ьэ, ьо, ьу (как вариант — апостроф вместо ь) — после согласных.

Это предложение **не было принято**. А. Н. Гвоздев отмечает, что использование букв я, е, ё, ю, и, когда они обозначают сочетание йота и последующего гласного, приводит **к значительной экономии места,** их исключение и замена на й+соответствующий гласный увеличило бы объем печатаемых текстов примерно на 4–6 %.

А. Б. Шапиро также отмечает **удобство русской графики:** «Наличие в алфавите букв я, ё, е, ю для обозначения слога, состоящего из согласного «йот» и, соответственно, гласных а, о, э, у, позволяет обозначать эти слоги одной буквой вместо двух (согласный «йот» плюс буква для гласного звука), как это имеет место в ряде других языков, например, в немецком, польском, чешском.